# how to execute Statement before commit when use jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to use PolarDB-X with jpa.
but I can not to use JpaTransactionManager.

when use PolarDB-X with jdbc , it must be create TransactionManager like this.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionDefinition;

public class DrdsTransactionManager extends DataSourceTransactionManager {
    public DrdsTransactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        super(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    protected void prepareTransactionalConnection(Connection con, TransactionDefinition definition) throws SQLException {
        try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement()) {
            stmt.executeUpdate("SET drds_transaction_policy = '2PC'");
        }
    }
}
```

this PolarDB-X doc is here

https://help.aliyun.com/apsara/enterprise/v_3_12_0_20200630/drds/user-guide/distributed-transactions-based-on-mysql-5-6.html?spm=a2c4g.14484438.10001.100

but I can not find how to set this with JpaTransactionManager.

In my application,if i change the default JpaTransactionManager to DataSourceTransactionManager, it can not be save anything. the TransactionManager is not work.

are there some way to execute "SET drds_transaction_policy = '2PC'" in
JpaTransactionManager when begin a transaction?

Are there some body help me ?

Comment: In spring-boot with spring-data-jpa  application, the default transactionManager is JpaTransactionManager,  I can't substitute DataSourceTransactionManager for JpaTransactionManager.It will be error if i change the default JpaTransactionManager to DataSourceTransactionManager

Answer (score 0):

have you tried exposing your implementation as a bean of type `TransactionManager`?

From what I see in Spring Boot's `DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration` class, the default transaction manager is only instantiated when there is no bean of type `TransactionManager` on the classpath.

However, I haven't checked what other auto-config classes do, but I think it's worth a try :-)

Comment: In spring-boot with spring-data-jpa application, the default transactionManager is JpaTransactionManager, I can't substitute DataSourceTransactionManager for JpaTransactionManager.It will be error if i change the default JpaTransactionManager to DataSourceTransactionManage